# Hibernate outer join with null "base/root" entity

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a simple `Parent->Child` relationship in hibernate; some children do not have a parent.

I want to make a query, using an outer join, in hibernate, which brings a list of Parent entities.
The query itself is simple enough; my problem is that *I want to also bring those children that do not have a parent*.

What happens is that because I'm making the query on the `Parent` entity (I need to), and the `Parent` entity is null, no children are fetched.
What I want to see instead are `Parent` entities, with all their fields null, but with non-null children.

Do you know if this can be done in hibernate?

Comment: sounds like you might be over-complicating it, even if possible, it would most likely be "unperformant", is there anything against doing two queries? One for the parents and another for the "children" without parents. BTW, I'm assuming the parent and children are of different types

Comment: Sounds like it, but I don't think that I am over-complicating it. Don't know why you say it's "underperformant" : it's a simple outer join based on an indexed FK; as much as joins go, this is the quickest.
Yes, two queries are possible (that's what I'm doing now). But I want to refactor the code towards one single query (there are reasons for this).

Comment: That's fair, but you're retrieving the the Parent entity, from what I can tell, there is no possibility to retrieve a "null" Parent that has a list of "Children" :/ Maybe you can do something like SELECT * FROM Parent p LEFT OUTER JOIN p.children c WHERE c.parent_id IS NULL? This is totally untested, and of course you would have to map the results manually

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding; a similar query to the one you've mentioned I've already tried, and is giving me null objects (instead of empty Parent object, with all objects as nulls).

Comment: I don't think you'll ever get an empty Parent object, at most you'll get a List<Object[]> which you'll then have to map manually (each list element is a row and each array element is a column)

Comment: You're probably right (at least that's the most I've been able to find so far); would like to see if anyone has another idea; maybe this can still be avoided.

Comment: Maybe someone does :) I don't think you can do what you want, BUT, I also don't know everything about hibernate and that's why stack overflow exists :) Good luck